# Hovering above interactive chart with Plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I am creating Treemap with Plotly. Below you can see my data and my code

```
library(plotly)

df1<-structure(list(
  item=c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9", "item10",
    "item11", "item12", "item13", "item14", "item15", "item16", "item17", "item18", "item19", "item20", "item21","item22"),
  manuf = c("AMC", "Cadillac", "Camaro", "Chrysler", 
                              "Datsun", "Dodge", "Duster", "Ferrari", "Fiat", "Ford", "Honda", 
                              "Hornet", "Lincoln", "Lotus", "Maserati", "Mazda", "Merc", "Pontiac", 
                              "Porsche", "Toyota", "Valiant", "Volvo"), count = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                  1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                                  2L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                   "data.frame"))

df1$test<-c("test")

treemap<-plot_ly(data = df1,
                 type= "treemap",
                 values= ~count,
                 labels= ~item,
                 parents=  ~test,
                 domain= list(column=0),
                 name = " ",
                 textinfo="label+value+percent parent")  %>%
  layout(title="", 
         annotations =
           list(x = 0, y = -0.1,
                title = "", 
                text = " ",
                showarrow = F,
                xref='paper',
                yref='paper'))

treemap
```

This plot generate Treemap which can see below
[image]

So far, so good. However, when I hover my mouse over the Treemap, I can't see the names of the cars. For example, Item 17 is a Mercedes (Merc), but I can't see it when I hover over it. Can anybody help me solve this problem and display the names of the cars when I hover over them

Comment: To `plot_ly`, add `hovertext = "df1$manuf"`. Currently, there is no connection between the data with the manufacturer's name and your plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Kat was pointing out, you can use `hovertext = df1$manuf` as follow:
This code works in plotly v4.10.2

```r
library(plotly)

df1<-structure(list(
  item=c("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5", "item6", "item7", "item8", "item9", "item10",
         "item11", "item12", "item13", "item14", "item15", "item16", "item17", "item18", "item19", "item20", "item21","item22"),
  manuf = c("AMC", "Cadillac", "Camaro", "Chrysler", 
            "Datsun", "Dodge", "Duster", "Ferrari", "Fiat", "Ford", "Honda", 
            "Hornet", "Lincoln", "Lotus", "Maserati", "Mazda", "Merc", "Pontiac", 
            "Porsche", "Toyota", "Valiant", "Volvo"), count = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 
                                                                2L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                 "data.frame"))

df1$test<-c("test")

treemap<-plot_ly(data = df1,
                 type= "treemap",
                 values= ~count,
                 labels= ~item,
                 parents=  ~test,
                 domain= list(column=0),
                 name = " ",
                 hovertext = ~manuf, ## This allows you to add any text to your plots
                 textinfo="label+value+percent parent")  %>% 
  layout(title="", 
         annotations =
           list(x = 0, y = -0.1,
                title = "", 
                text = " ",
                showarrow = F,
                xref='paper',
                yref='paper'))

treemap
```

[image]